# How to stick Title for ViewPager to the TOP. PagerTitleStrip Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have some strange for me issue with ViewPager.

I need to add PagerTitleStrip to my ViewPager and put it on top. I try to put layout_gravity = "top", it reserves space for it on "bottom" and show title string on "top"!

When I put gravitity to "bottom", it displays correctly.

Here is screens

top - http://clip2net.com/s/4WDDUJ

bottom - http://clip2net.com/s/4WDD8k

ViewPager - green
PagerTitleStrip - blue
pager content match_parrent - red

Please help me to understand why it happens. How to stick to the top and dont have the green space on bottom?

Thank you.

Here is xml for pager:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pagerTelefoonInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1AF00F"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pagerTitleStrip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3AFFEF"
        android:layout_gravity="top" >
    </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is activity:

```
public class APager extends Activity {

ViewPager pager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_pager);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);


}


private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
            break;
        case 1:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
            break;
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Title " + position;
    }

    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
    // public int getItemPosition(Object object) { return POSITION_NONE; }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the viewPager layout set up I have that works correctly with the strip on top:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"/>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Just made the same layout as yours and still the same..moreover I added paddings 14dp and see what happens http://clip2net.com/s/4WDPfm

it creates 2 titles... on top an on bottom where is part of ViewPager ((

Comment: Can you post your code that's setting up the viewpager as well?

Comment: xml contents (fragment1 and fragment2) just linearlayout match_parrent

Comment: instead of using pagerAdapter, try using FragmentStatePagerAdapter from the support v4 package.

Comment: problem solved by using .addView(view); instead of .addView(view, 0);

p.s. how I can access all views on all fragemtns on my activity in case with FragmentStatePagerAdapter ? thank you for help anyway ))

Comment: you can use the mAdapter.getFragment() method to get the fragment, and use getView() to find the view you need